# Hide and show output panel in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

Can anyone tell me how to hide and show the output panel in visualforce page
My usecase is:
I have 2 output panel. In the first I have a commandlink when I click on the link the 1st outputpanel should get hide and 2nd one get display and same for output panel 2

I have tried following code but it doesnt give the expected

**VFP**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController1">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection id="search">

<apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper1">
<apex:outputPanel id="panel1" rendered="{!rend1}" layout="block">
```

**First Panel**

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction}" value="show second"  reRender="thePanelWrapper2" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

**Second Panel**

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction1}" value="show first"  reRender="thePanelWrapper1" />
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class MyController1{

    public MyController1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        rend = false;
    }

    public MyController1(){
          rend = false;
    }
    public Boolean rend{get;set;}
    public Boolean rend1{get;set;}

    public void commandLinkAction(){
        rend=true;
        rend1=false;

        // return null;
    }

    public void commandLinkAction1(){
        rend1=true;
        rend=false;
    }

}
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code.

**Updated Code**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController1">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection id="search">

<apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper1">
    <apex:outputPanel id="panel1" rendered="{!rend1}" layout="block">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction}" value="show second"  reRender="thePanelWrapper2" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper2">
    <apex:outputPanel id="panel2" rendered="{!!rend1}" layout="block">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction1}" value="show first"  reRender="thePanelWrapper1" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>


</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController1{


public MyController1(){
          rend1 = true;
   }

   public Boolean rend1{get;set;}

   public void commandLinkAction(){

      rend1=false;

     // return null;
   }
    public void commandLinkAction1(){
        rend1=true;


    }

}
```

Comment: Id `id="panel1"` for one panel is a mistake ? You try to rerender with this id instead : `reRender="thePanelWrapper2"`.

Comment: @SF_user : it doesnt work

Comment: @SF_user: can you give me sample code for this

Comment: Using Javascript for doing that can be a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Controller:

```
public class MyController1{

public Boolean render1{get;set;}
public Boolean render2{get;set;}

public MyController1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    render1 = true;
    render2 = false;
}

public MyController1(){
    render1 = true;
    render2 = false;
}


public void hide1Show2(){
    render1=false;
    render2=true;

}

public void hide2Show1(){
    render1=true;
    render2=false;
}

}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController1">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="search">

        <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper1">
          <apex:outputPanel id="panel1" rendered="{!render1}" layout="block">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!hide1Show2}" value="show second"  reRender="thePanelWrapper1,thePanelWrapper2" />
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper2">
          <apex:outputPanel id="panel2" rendered="{!render2}" layout="block">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!hide2Show1}" value="show first"  reRender="thePanelWrapper1,thePanelWrapper2" />
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>


    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: [~user3332076] did you try the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<apex:page controller="MyController1">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="search">

     <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper1">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction}" value="show second"  onclick="showPanel('second')" />
     </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper2" layout="block" style="display: none">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction}" value="show first"  onclick="showPanel('first')" />
    </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlockSection> 
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showPanel(panel) {
            if(panel == 'first') {
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.search.thePanelWrapper1}').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.search.thePanelWrapper2}').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.search.thePanelWrapper1}').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.search.thePanelWrapper2}').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: it gives both output panel by default

Comment: Initially it will show panel1

Comment: after clicking first panel link then it will show second panel content and hide the first panel content

Comment: I edited my answer to initially hide the second panel. Otherwise it works ?

Comment: It doesnt work man.. Can you give me the working code

Comment: What doesn't work ?

Comment: I edited my answer changing the id. In `document.getElementById('{!$Component.search.thePanelWrapper1}')` you should have the list of Ids. If it doesn't work again, check with a console like Firebug what is the real Id of your panel and put it in the `getElementById` function.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your VF code a bit. See if this works for you. Note the changes in the `rerender` attributes and value in the `rendered` attribute

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController1">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection id="search">

<apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper1">
    <apex:outputPanel id="panel1" rendered="{!rend1}" layout="block">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction}" value="show second"  reRender="thePanelWrapper2,thePanelWrapper1" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper2">
    <apex:outputPanel id="panel2" rendered="{!!rend1}" layout="block">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!commandLinkAction1}" value="show first"  reRender="thePanelWrapper1,thePanelWrapper2" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>


</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller** ( same as the one you posted in the question )

```
public class MyController1{

    public MyController1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    rend = false;
    }
public MyController1(){
          rend = false;
   }
   public Boolean rend{get;set;}
   public Boolean rend1{get;set;}

   public void commandLinkAction(){
      rend=true;
      rend1=false;

     // return null;
   }
    public void commandLinkAction1(){
        rend1=true;
        rend=false;

    }

}
```

**Screenshot of working example.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: My use case is I have 2 output panel and each panel has one button which is used to show another panel

Comment: If I click the button in first panel then it will show the content of second panel and hide the content of first panel and same for second panel button

Comment: But in this code the content of panel is not hiding after clicking the buttton

Comment: It does for me. Try this code as a new page. Note the changes for `rerender` attribute. Maybe you didn't change that in your code.

Comment: it doesnt work man

Comment: Maybe there are some other elements conflicting on your page. I updated the answer with controller code as well (in case you changed it later). It works as it is. Note that I use only one variable to control the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your Controller.

```
public class MyController1{

    public Boolean panel1 {get; private set;}
    public Boolean panel2 {get; private set;}

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        panel1 = true;
        panel2 = false;
    }

    public void displayPanel1(){
        panel1 = true;
        panel2 = false;
    }

    public void displayPanel2(){
        panel1 = false;
        panel2 = true;
    }
}
```

And this for your VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="MyController1">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="search">

      <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper1" >
        <apex:outputPanel id="panel1" layout="block" rendered="{!panel1}" >
          <apex:commandLink action="{!displayPanel2}" value="show second"  reRender="thePanelWrapper1, thePanelWrapper2" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:outputPanel>

      <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelWrapper2"  >
        <apex:outputPanel id="panel2" layout="block" rendered="{!panel2}">
          <apex:commandLink action="{!displayPanel1}" value="show first"  reRender="thePanelWrapper1, thePanelWrapper2" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The commandLinks must rerender both panels, the outerpanels are the ones that need rerendered, but the render tag should be in the inner panels.